# Nissan Sentra SE-R p1490

Tags: nissan, p1490

I have a 2002 Nissan Sentra SE-R with a P1490 Code. What's wrong with the car?

Comment: What do you mean by that I was asking what cars and parts are compatiable with mine

Answer (score 1):

The OBDII system on your vehicle has an EVAP sub-system. The EVAP system vents the fuel tank fumes to the vehicles inlet manifold and are burnt by the engine. This prevents HC's being released to the atmosphere. The system will have a vent valve, purge valve, charcoal canister, control valve and hosing with its associated wiring to operate the valves. P1490 is an indication that the control valve is not operating correctly. You need to check the operation of the system. The easy way is with a bi-directional Nissan scanner, repair shop. The scenic route involves a full inspection of the wiring and components and jump wiring the valves with an external voltage to check operation, **NOT recommended unless you are totally familiar with the system and the fire risks.**

Comment: Ok what vehicles are compatible with mine its a 2002 nissan sentra se-r

Comment: Here in the UK we have a range of scanners, Snap-ON, Autel, Sealey, Carsoft etc etc. I have two laptops with various software, an Autel DS708 for everyday use, five hand held computers, and a couple of data loggers. To recommend any particular scanner would depend on the use it is going to be put too. For a one off job on your EVAP I would recommend a scan at your local repair shop. The alternative would be an expensive scanner, thousands of pounds for Snap-ON, which may only be used the one time, making it econmomically un-viable.

Comment: One thought I have just had. I bought an ELM obdII-andoid interface and a copy of Torque-Pro. Together they came to under unde £15. I regard it as a highly sophisticated toy, but it will give you codes and a lot of fun. A couple of customers of our's have used it lately and I got involved with it so I could read their song sheet.